# SSE Code runs 30% faster, yet when in use show over 20% CPU increase

Tags: c, sse

I'm attempting to optimise a routine used in VLC, that converts NV12 frame into a YV12 frame.

For background information, NV12 is identical to YV12 with the exception that the U and V chroma plane are interleaved.
So to convert one format into another, it's simply a matter of deinterleaving a channel like:
UVUVUVUVUVUVU
becomes
UUUUUUU
VVVVVVV

The routine I'm attempting to improve is this one:
http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=modules/video_chroma/copy.c;h=d29843c037e494170f0d6bc976bea8439dd6115b;hb=HEAD#l286

Now, the primary issue with this routine, is that it requires a 16-bytes aligned memory cache as intermediary storage
So the routine first deinterleave the data into the cache (4kiB max) and then copy the result found in the cache back into the destination frame.

I have rewritten this function, so it doesn't require the use of a cache, using SSE2/3 instructions working on unaligned memory when required, and instructions using aligned memory when possible.

The code is as follow:

```
static void SSE_SplitPlanes(uint8_t *dstu, size_t dstu_pitch,
                            uint8_t *dstv, size_t dstv_pitch,
                            const uint8_t *src, size_t src_pitch,
                            uint8_t *cache, size_t cache_size,
                            unsigned width, unsigned height, unsigned cpu)
{
    VLC_UNUSED(cache);
    VLC_UNUSED(cache_size);

    const uint8_t shuffle[] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,
                                1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 };
    const uint8_t mask[] = { 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
                             0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00 };
    const bool aligned = ((uintptr_t)src & 0xf) == 0;

    asm volatile ("mfence");

#define LOAD64A \
    "movdqa  0(%[src]), %%xmm0\n" \
    "movdqa 16(%[src]), %%xmm1\n" \
    "movdqa 32(%[src]), %%xmm2\n" \
    "movdqa 48(%[src]), %%xmm3\n"

#define LOAD64U \
    "movdqu  0(%[src]), %%xmm0\n" \
    "movdqu 16(%[src]), %%xmm1\n" \
    "movdqu 32(%[src]), %%xmm2\n" \
    "movdqu 48(%[src]), %%xmm3\n"

#define STORE2X32 \
    "movq   %%xmm0,   0(%[dst1])\n" \
    "movq   %%xmm1,   8(%[dst1])\n" \
    "movhpd %%xmm0,   0(%[dst2])\n" \
    "movhpd %%xmm1,   8(%[dst2])\n" \
    "movq   %%xmm2,  16(%[dst1])\n" \
    "movq   %%xmm3,  24(%[dst1])\n" \
    "movhpd %%xmm2,  16(%[dst2])\n" \
    "movhpd %%xmm3,  24(%[dst2])\n"

    if (aligned)
    {
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            unsigned x = 0;

#ifdef CAN_COMPILE_SSSE3
            if (vlc_CPU_SSSE3()) {
                for (x = 0; x < (width & ~31); x += 32) {
                    asm volatile (
                        "movdqu (%[shuffle]), %%xmm7\n"
                        LOAD64A
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm0\n"
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm1\n"
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm2\n"
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm3\n"
                        STORE2X32
                        : : [dst1]"r"(&dstu[x]), [dst2]"r"(&dstv[x]), [src]"r"(&src[2*x]), [shuffle]"r"(shuffle) : "memory", "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm7");
                }
            } else
#endif
            {
                for (x = 0; x < (width & ~31); x += 32) {
                    asm volatile (
                        "movdqu (%[mask]), %%xmm7\n"
                        LOAD64A
                        "movdqa   %%xmm0, %%xmm4\n"
                        "movdqa   %%xmm1, %%xmm5\n"
                        "movdqa   %%xmm2, %%xmm6\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm0\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm1\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm7, %%xmm4\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm7, %%xmm5\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm7, %%xmm6\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm4, %%xmm0\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm5, %%xmm1\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm3, %%xmm7\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm2\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm3\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm6, %%xmm2\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm7, %%xmm3\n"
                        STORE2X32
                        : : [dst2]"r"(&dstu[x]), [dst1]"r"(&dstv[x]), [src]"r"(&src[2*x]), [mask]"r"(mask) : "memory", "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4", "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7");
                }
            }

            for (; x < width; x++) {
                dstu[x] = src[2*x+0];
                dstv[x] = src[2*x+1];
            }
            src  += src_pitch;
            dstu += dstu_pitch;
            dstv += dstv_pitch;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            unsigned x = 0;

#ifdef CAN_COMPILE_SSSE3
            if (vlc_CPU_SSSE3()) {
                for (x = 0; x < (width & ~31); x += 32) {
                    asm volatile (
                        "movdqu (%[shuffle]), %%xmm7\n"
                        LOAD64U
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm0\n"
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm1\n"
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm2\n"
                        "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm3\n"
                        STORE2X32
                        : : [dst1]"r"(&dstu[x]), [dst2]"r"(&dstv[x]), [src]"r"(&src[2*x]), [shuffle]"r"(shuffle) : "memory", "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm7");
                }
            } else
#endif  
            {
                for (x = 0; x < (width & ~31); x += 32) {
                    asm volatile (
                        "movdqu (%[mask]), %%xmm7\n"
                        LOAD64U
                        "movdqu   %%xmm0, %%xmm4\n"
                        "movdqu   %%xmm1, %%xmm5\n"
                        "movdqu   %%xmm2, %%xmm6\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm0\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm1\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm7, %%xmm4\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm7, %%xmm5\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm7, %%xmm6\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm4, %%xmm0\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm5, %%xmm1\n"
                        "pand     %%xmm3, %%xmm7\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm2\n"
                        "psrlw    $8,     %%xmm3\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm6, %%xmm2\n"
                        "packuswb %%xmm7, %%xmm3\n"
                        STORE2X32
                        : : [dst2]"r"(&dstu[x]), [dst1]"r"(&dstv[x]), [src]"r"(&src[2*x]), [mask]"r"(mask) : "memory", "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4", "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7");
                }
            }

            for (; x < width; x++) {
                dstu[x] = src[2*x+0];
                dstv[x] = src[2*x+1];
            }
            src  += src_pitch;
            dstu += dstu_pitch;
            dstv += dstv_pitch;
        }
    }
#undef STORE2X32
#undef LOAD64U
#undef LOAD64A
}
```

Now, benchmarking this function alone, it runs around 26% faster on an i7-2600 CPU (ivybridge 3.4GHz), a little faster on an i7-4650U (haswell 1.7GHz) with a 30% speed increase over the original function

Which was expected as you go from 2 reads + 2 writes, to 1 read + 1 write.

However, when used within VLC (the function is used to display every frame decoded via Intel VAAPI interface), the CPU usage for the same video jumps from 20% to 32-34%

So I'm puzzled why that would be. and how could that be resolved.
I had expected an opposite result.
Both routines use SSE2/3, one runs faster, yet cause increase CPU usage

thanks

Comment: How do you measure CPU usage? On which OS?

Comment: I simply run top side-by-side. This is a linux ubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.13

Comment: "I would expect that for a given CPU intensive workload, higher CPU usage would lead to faster execution time." The pure-C code takes even more CPU usage, yet runs 8 times slower :)

Comment: Still confused about CPU use numbers: is it percent of one CPU, or of total? I.e. the 2600 hat 8 logical CPUs, 25% use means for example 2 CPUs at 100% and 6 idle. The 4650 only has 4 logical CPUs, and should have about twice the CPU use. My suspicion is that the SSE code somehow has an effect on OS CPU time accounting.

Comment: Just to be sure: the original code was pure C? And, could you disable hyperthreading and turbo mode in BIOS and repeat the measurements, to get some variables out of the equation?

Comment: @jyavenard: That indicates the CPU was not spending that time doing "useful" work (in contrast to, say, handling TLB misses). CPU utilization is not an absolute measure - how about you measure other things about your code too?

Comment: Do you have the same framerate in the two experiments ?

Comment: The video played is always the same, a 1080 H264 video. There's no change between runs in the conditions: always the same clip. @Chris: I only mentioned C to indicate on how much faster the SSE performs the same task. The main aim of using hardware accelerated video decoding, is in my opinion reduced CPU usage, so you can do more at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: what other thing would you want to measure? To benchmark the code, and have proper coverage. I have unit-tests that run the code in a loop converting 1 minute worth of 48fps frames. It is run on frames with various dimensions, with various memory alignment and various stride sizes

Comment: CPU %, in even the best of circumstances, is a highly fictitious number.  Was not so bad on the old unis and your early multis, but with modern processors there's no way to arrive at a meaningful value which will appear consistent in a situation such as your.

Comment: How about memory/cache hits/misses, instructions completed, total cycles?

Comment: While the above comment by @HotLicks is spot on, you could still possibly get a useful approximation by measuring CPU seconds instead of CPU % - multiply the CPU % by the actual time. So for example an algorithm running at 20% CPU usage for 1 minute gives about 12 seconds CPU time used, while one running at say 40% for 20 seconds uses 8 CPU seconds. The second algorithm is an improvement in total CPU usage, and accomplishes more work per unit time than the first.

Comment: @twalberg I take this to be implicit in the form of the benchmark: the actual time is fixed to the length of the video being played in both the “before” and the “after” measurements.

Comment: @twalberg: I did a test... play a 1 minute video then exit. Using the time command: With old routine: user 0m12.494s sys 0m1.893s, with new routine: user 0m16.029s sys 0m1.790s. So even looking at user time, more CPU time was spent. Yet, running my unit-tests converting 1440 times a 1080 frame takes 463ms, and with the new routine it takes 341ms... So very puzzling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.

I've found out what was going on.

While the new routine is much faster with traditional memory, when it comes to working on frames generated by hardware decode method, it is actually slower:

This Intel white paper explains things:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/copying-accelerated-video-decode-frame-buffers

All my benchmarks and tests were done using traditionally allocated memory. Not from Uncacheable Speculative Write Combining (USWC)

back to the drawing board